# setting popup box value based on the specific link clicked

Tags: forms, popup

> I have a slider gallery it contains links below the image. I want to
>   show a popup box with a form and the name of the image to be auto
>   selected in the popup form.
>
> I have done till this
>
> the popup box is appearing on the link clicked. I have also set the
>   link with value like this :

```
<a href="#?id=1"  data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade" >Make an enquiry</a>
```

> This is the code through which i am fetching the value of the link

```
<?php
            if (isset($_GET['id'])){
                if($_GET['id']=='1')
                echo '<td><input type="text" name="product" style="width:200px; height:30px; !important" value="Testvalue"></td></tr>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<td><input type="text" name="product" style="width:200px; height:30px; !important" ></td></tr>';
            }
            ?>
```

> But I am getting a blank textbox .. Where am I going wrong ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<a href="?id=1#"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you niomaster. But the thing is the popup is not taking value from the link as it is fetching it from url (If I am opening the link in another page then the value comes in popup) but it is not coming in the same page.